# JS Callback (passing data to D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback

New to JS so pardon the sloppy code. I'm looping through a set of URLs, populating an array with a value from those urls and *trying* to pass the array to D3. Manual coding of the array returns the result just fine but I can't seem to get it to work with the callback:

```
total = []

function get(url) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status == 200) {
    resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };
    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };
    // Make the request
    req.send();
  });
}


function hope(url){
get(url).then(function(response) {
  return JSON.parse(response);
}).then(function(response) {
  total.push(response.totalCount);
//console.log(total);
return total;
});
}

function getData( callback ) {
for (i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) { 
url = arra[i];
hope(url);
}
callback(total);
}


function chartIt(total){
console.log(total);
d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(total)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
}

getData( function(){
  chartIt(total);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke your callback just after the loop probably none of the requests has finished yet since they are asynchronous. You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to ensure that all of the promises has been resolved.

```
function getData(callback) {
    var requests = arra.map(function(url) { return hope(url); });
    Promise.all(requests)
        .then(function(results) {
            callback(total);
        })
}
```

To make it work you also need to return a promise from the `hope` function which is pretty easy because your `get` function already returns a promise - just pass it forward:

```
function hope(url) {
     return get(url).then({...})
}
```

---

*Extra hint*: you could get rid of the global `total` variable by returning `response.totalCount` from the `hope` function:

```
function hope(url) {
    return get(url).then(function(response) {
        return JSON.parse(response);
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.totalCount;
    });
}
```

Then the `results` in `getData` would be exactly what current `total` is - an array of `totalCount`'s from particular responses. So you could call your callback like this:

```
 callback(results);
```

Comment: Ty for the pointers, especially promise.all! I updated getData to use callback(results), removing the global as you suggested but the data is not being passed. Oddly, if I put in console.log, I see that results is populated as it should be.

Comment: Correction - replaced the callback(results) with functionName(results) and all is well :-)   Ty again!